# I am getting org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException in Mapreduce job?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have installed hadoop using following points.

1. Installed hadoop using tar file
2. created hdfs user and group and assigned them to hadoop folder
3. then created hdfs directories for namenode and datanode in /opt folder
4. Configuration files are also set.

But when i tried to run **hadoop jar hadoop-examples-1.0.0.jar pi 4 100** I am getting this error.

```
2014-11-05 12:12:02,978 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block null bad datanode[0] nodes == null 
2014-11-05 12:12:02,978 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient: Could not get block locations. Source file "/tmp/hadoop-hdfs/mapred/system/jobtracker.info" - Aborting...
2014-11-05 12:12:02,979 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Writing to file   hdfs://hostname:9000/tmp/hadoop-hdfs/mapred/system/jobtracker.info failed! 
2014-11-05 12:12:02,979 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: FileSystem is not ready yet!
2014-11-05 12:12:02,982 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobTracker: Failed to initialize recovery manager.

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File /tmp/hadoop-hdfs/mapred/system/jobtracker.info could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:1556)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.addBlock(NameNode.java:696)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor7.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:563)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1388)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:1384)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1083)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:1382)

     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1066)
     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.addBlock(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
     at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
     at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.addBlock(Unknown Source)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.locateFollowingBlock(DFSClient.java:3507)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSClient.java:3370)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream.access$2700(DFSClient.java:2586)
     at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSClient.java:2826)
```

One thing here I want to mention is that I have set hdfs paths to `/mnt` direcotry but hdfs still pointing to `/tmp/hadoop-hdfs`

Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Did you format your namenode? check whether all your datanodes are started

Comment: Yes I have formatted namenode. I deleted contents of /tmp/hadoop-hdfs/dfs/data and /tmp/hadoop-hdfs/dfs/name directories. Same error again. I am wondering why hadoop hdfs is pointing or storing data in /tmp directories, if I have set configuration to /mnt direcory

Comment: looks like there is a problem with the datanode. can check all your datanode running fine.

Comment: yes datanode is running i can see it after jps command and i can execute this command hadoop fs -ls / successfully

Comment: check if your datanode(port) is blocking the namenode.

Comment: Thanks shri. Now everything is working fine. I changed my configuration files according to this article 

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Answer (score 0):

> Check all the paths of the action node you are trying to run,this usually occurs due to wrong input/output paths provided.
>
> Also if you are rerunning a workflow job,make sure all the events and properties provided in coordinator.xml(or job.xml) must be present in job.properties,because rerunning a workflow job doesn't refer to job.xml as against in the case of normal coordinator job run(scheduled running).